# How to get the output path of a .NET Core app via MSBuild?

Tags: .net, msbuild, asp.net-core, .net-core, project.json

I have a .NET Core project that targets the .NET Framework as per my project.json file;

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": { }
    }
}
```

I am trying to find a way to copy some (native) dependencies to my output build directory but I am struggling to find the correct way to do it.

When I build this project my output goes to `bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64`. I'm wondering if there is a method to retrieve the output path? `$(TargetDir)` gives me my `bin\` directory, but is there a variable to retrieve `bin\Debug\%FRAMEWORK%\%RUNTIME%`?

Also should I be using project.json Scripts over MSBuild?

**EDIT - May 2017** Please see my answer below. In short, this was never supported by `project.json`, however this question is no longer relevant given the deprecation of `project.json` in VS2017.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT - May 2017**

Visual Studio tooling has now moved up to version 15 with the introduction of Visual Studio 2017 and with this release `global.json`, `project.json` and `.xproj` have been phased out in favour of `.csproj` project files. VS2017 will provide a one-way migration when opening the solution.

See here for migration documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/migration/

See here for a comparison between the two:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj

Comment: That's not for msbuild.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You should migrate to MSBuild based project for your .NET Core applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a postpublish script to your project.json in which you would copy the native bits to `%publish:OutputPath%`. Another option is to add the files you want to include to:

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    ...
```

Comment: The files I need to include are native DLLs which are part of a NuGet package (CefSharp), the issues I'm experiencing is that `dotnet run` and `dotnet publish` are missing these dependencies completely so I need to include them somewhere. There's a good 50 dependency files in total so I didn't want to have to type them all out manually...

Comment: dotnet publish can only publish native dependencies if the package follows the `runtimes/{RID}/*` structure (see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Libuv/ for an example). Since before there was not really any convention for packages with native libraries dotnet does not handle it. You can use a globbing pattern in includes (and you can also use `mappings` so if all dlls are in a subfolder this might be just a single line (something like `"include": [`dependencies/**/*.dll]`)